# Bars not appearing

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Below is my code.

I am trying to make a bar chart with animation. 
Below is the table which is linked with the file.

Letter          Frequency

Belgium         0.174757282
Denmark         0.009708738
France          0.349514563
Germany         0.009708738
Ireland Irish   0.009708738
Italy           0.097087379
Luxembourg      0.048543689
Netherlands     0.019417476
Spain           0.116504854
Switzerland     0.019417476
United Kingdom  0.038834951
USA             0.029126214
Australia       0.009708738
Results voided  0.067961165

However, the bars are not appearing. It would be great if someone could help. Thanks a lot

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

 .bar {
    border: 10px solid #0b3536;
    border-radius: 6px;
    fill: #0098d8;
  }

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}




</style>
<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>

// Mike Bostock "margin conventions"
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// D3 scales = just math
// x is a function that transforms from "domain" (data) into "range" (usual pixels)
// domain gets set after the data loads
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0.5]);

// D3 Axis - renders a d3 scale in SVG
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()

    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5, "%");

// create an SVG element (appended to body)
// set size
// add a "g" element (think "group")
// annoying d3 gotcha - the 'svg' variable here is a 'g' element
// the final line sets the transform on <g>, not on <svg>
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text") // just for the title (ticks are automatic)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)") // rotate the text!
    .attr("y", 1)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

// d3.tsv is a wrapper around XMLHTTPRequest, returns array of arrays (?) for a TSV file
// type function transforms strings to numbers, dates, etc.
d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  replay(data);
});

function type(d) {
  // + coerces to a Number from a String (or anything)
  d.Frequency = +d.Frequency;
  return d;
}

function replay(data) {
  var slices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    slices.push(data.slice(0, i+1));
  }
  slices.forEach(function(slice, index){
    setTimeout(function(){
      draw(slice);
    }, index * 300);
  });
}

function draw(data) {
  // measure the domain (for x, unique letters) (for y [0,maxFrequency])
  // now the scales are finished and usable
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Frequency; })]);

  // another g element, this time to move the origin to the bottom of the svg element
  // someSelection.call(thing) is roughly equivalent to thing(someSelection[i])
  //   for everything in the selection\
  // the end result is g populated with text and lines!
  svg.select(".x.axis").transition().duration(300).call(xAxis);

  // same for yAxis but with more transform and a title
  svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(300).call(yAxis)

  // THIS IS THE ACTUAL WORK!
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data, function(d) { return d.Letter; }) // (data) is an array/iterable thing, second argument is an ID generator function

  bars.exit()
    .transition()
      .duration(300)
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0))
    .style('fill-opacity', 0.00001024)
    .remove();

  // data that needs DOM = enter() (a set/selection, not an event!)
  bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0));

  // the "UPDATE" set:
  bars.transition().duration(300).attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Letter); }) // (d) is one item from the data array, x is the scale object from above
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Frequency); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Frequency); }); // flip the height, because y's domain is bottom up, but SVG renders top down

}


</script>
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you sure your data.tsv content is what you posted? Since if you console.log(data) you will see that Frequency is NaN (Not a Number), In your type(d) function, if you console.log(d) you'll see exactly the same.

Comment: use `transition.delay()` instead of your slices-setTimeout method

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. really appreciate it. As I am very new to this field, it would be great if you could provide more detail.

Comment: Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"   {Belgium 0.174757282: "Denmark 0.009708738", Frequency: NaN}